# How to show my selected value of dropdownlist in textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a code which is used to populate the words from text file to listbox. If i select any value from listbox then it display a selected word within the text box (within the form - to post the value to another script)

**javascript code:**

```
<script>
  function getSelectedValue(theValue){
    document.getElementById('pasteTheValue').innerHTML=theValue;
  }
</script>
```

**php code:**

```
//open the file
$read_your_file = @fopen($your_file, "r") or die ("Couldn't Access $your_file");

//create a variable to hold the contents of the file
$contents_your_file = fread($read_your_file, filesize($your_file));

//array of file contents
$your_array = explode("\n",$contents_your_file);

//close the file
fclose($read_your_file);

//counts the number elements in the property_categories array
$num_elmnts_array = count($your_array) ;

//elements in the drop down list
//$drop_elmnts = 0;

//begin creating your dropdown menu...

$your_menu = "<select name=\"list\" onchange=\"getSelectedValue(this.value)\">";  
//For loop to begin
for($counter = 0; $counter < $num_elmnts_array; $counter++){
$your_menu .= "<option value=\"$your_array[$counter]\">$your_array[$counter]        </option>";
//$counter++;
}
//end select menu
$your_menu .= "</select>";
?>

<p><b><?php echo "$your_menu"; ?></b><br>
<p id="pasteTheValue"></p>
```

This works fine. This display a selected word as usual normal text within the page. But i want to show this (or get the value) within the text box. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Do you want to iterate your options with jquery, can you explain more.....

Comment: @prabu try using file_get_content in place of fread

Comment: where is your textbox in the code ?

Answer (score 1):

use a textbox with id like this

```
<input type="text" id="my_textbox" value="" />
```

Now change in your JS Function

```
function getSelectedValue(theValue){
 document.getElementById('pasteTheValue').innerHTML=theValue;
 document.getElementById('my_textbox').value=theValue; // add this line
}
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
 function getSelectedValue(theValue){
     document.getElementById('my_textbox').value=theValue; // add this line
    }
```

Comment: It works, thank you. but if i comment <p id="pasteTheValue"></p>, it will not work.

Comment: then you should also comment in the js function first line

Comment: Thank you Mr. SKRocks. It works well. Now i have to post this value to another jsp through submit button.

Answer (score 1):

Hope http://jsfiddle.net/o5xxz67f/  will help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').change(function(){
       alert($(this).val()); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting selected value from `listbox` to `p` tag, if you want to insert that inside of `textbox`, Use this code -

```
<input type="text" id="textboxid" value="" />
```

Now, in your js function -

```
function getSelectedValue(theValue){
   document.getElementById('pasteTheValue').innerHTML=theValue; // to insert in p tag
   document.getElementById('textboxid').value=theValue; // to insert inside of textbox
}
```

Comment: any difference from my answer?

Comment: No dude, i have not checked any answer while i was replying :)

Answer (score 0):

To get selected value you need to use `.value` in JavaScript and `.val()` in jQuery.

**Using JavaScript**

```
function getSelectedValue(theValue){
var SelectedValue = theValue.options[theValue.selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementById('pasteTheValue').innerHTML=SelectedValue ;
}
```

**Using jQuery**

```
$('select').change(function () {
var SelectedValue = $('select').val();
$('#pasteTheValue').innerHTML = SelectedValue;
}
```

`Source:` here is a complete tutorial on how to  [get selected value of dropdown list using javascript](http://www.aspneto.com/get-selected-value-or-text-of-asp-dot-net-dropdownlist-using-javascript.html)

Answer (score 0):

Consider Dropdown list element id as **myDropDown**.
Now your task can be done as shown below:

```
$("#myDropDown").change(function(){
   var selectedValue = $(this).val();
   $("#pasteTheValue").val(selectedValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this jsbin should help you
[jsbin_example](http://jsbin.com/hoqur/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
<select id='selectList' onClick="showSelected(this)">
  <option>list1</option>
  <option>list2</option>
  <option>list3</option>
  <option>list4</option>

  </select>
  <input type="text" id='show' />

function showSelected(thisObj)
{

  document.getElementById('show').value = thisObj.options[thisObj.selectedIndex].text;

}
```

If you are ok using jquery it should be even more easier

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementByID('listID').on('change',function(){
        var list  = document.getElementByID('listID');
        var indx = list.selectedIndex;
        document.getElementByID('otherFieldID').val(list[indx].text);
    });
});
```